# Populate ObjectListView using a List

Tags: c#, datasource, objectlistview

I'm trying to populate a DataTreeListView from ObjectListView library using a list. Unfortunately I am unable to achieve it, there is nothing displayed even though there is a count of item inside the List itself.

```
 Class.cs

 public class Class
 {
   protected string xName;
   protected int xId;
   protected int xParentId;
   protected int happinessStatus;
   protected int salaryStatus;

  public Class()
  {
  this.xName = "";
  this.xId = 0;
  this.xParentId = 0;
  this.happinessStatus = 0;
  this.salaryStatus = 0;
  }

  public String Name 
  {
    get { return this.xName; }
    set { this.xName = value; }
  }

  public int Id
  {
    get { return this.xId; }
    set { this.xId = value; }
   }

  public int ParentId
  {
   get { return this.xParentId; }
   set { this.xParentId = value; }
  }

  public int HappinessStatus
  {
    get {return this.happinessStatus; }
    set { this.happinessStatus = value; }
  }

  public int SalaryStatus
  {
    get { return this.salaryStatus; }
    set { this.salaryStatus = value; }
  }

  public static List<Class> GetList()
  {
     List<Class> oList = new List<Class>();
     Class oClass = new Class();

     oClass.Name = "Person A";
     oClass.Id = 1;
     oClass.ParentId = 0;
     oClass.HappinessStatus = 1;
     oClass.SalaryStatus = 1000;
     oList.Add(oClass);

     oClass.Name = "Person B";
     oClass.Id = 2;
     oClass.ParentId = 1;
     oClass.HappinessStatus = 1;
     oClass.SalaryStatus = 2000;
     oList.Add(oClass);

     oClass.Name = "Person C";
     oClass.Id = 3;
     oClass.ParentId = 1;
     oClass.HappinessStatus = 1;
     oClass.SalaryStatus = 1000;
     oList.Add(oClass);

     return oList; 
    }
```

On the MainForm's Load Event,

I did the following:

```
    List<Class> list = new List<Class>();
    list = Class.GetList();
    dataTreeListView1.DataSource = list;
```

On the designer view, I've also created columns which has got aspect name set to each of the property of the class file except the Id and ParentId.

KeyAspectName : Id
ParentKeyAspectName: ParentId

I did a small messagebox to show the count of the item in the list, its correct but nothing displayed out on the dataTreeListView control.

May I know what is wrong with my coding?

Comment: What platform is this Winforms, WPF, Asp.Net??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set `KeyAspectName`, `ParentKeyAspectName` and `RootKeyValue` accordingly?

If you did it using the designer, `RootKeyValue` may be your problem:

> Due to the limitations of the Designer in the IDE, RootKeyValue can only be given a string value through the IDE. If your ParentKey is not of type string, you will have to set its value through code.

Since you parent key is of type `int` use

```
dataTreeListView1.RootKeyValue = 0;
```

Note that in contrast to the basic OLV, you don't need to add columns manually. If you want to hide the key columns set `ShowKeyColumns = false`.

EDIT:
There is another mistake in you code. You add the same instance of the object `oClass` 3 times. Use `oClass = new Class();` before initializing a new person.

Comment: dataTreeListView1.RootKeyValue = 0; did the trick, thanks for the big help!

Comment: @user3167398  i am facing some issue  i am not able to show content on the datatreelistview can you please help me

Comment: i am facing some issue  i am not able to show content on the datatreelistview can you please help me i have done the same thing that you did all my codes are same as you but i am getting a tree list view with coloumn names but no content on it